# Disable Neo4j logical log "flush after commit" behavior

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to configure the logical log flush behavior of Neo4j, so that not after each committed transaction the data forced to the disk (even in cost of data loss)?
We are using Neo4J on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could cast your GraphDatabaseService to a GraphDatabaseAPI and do:

db.tx().unforced().begin();

instead of

db.beginTx();

An unforced transaction will just write to the logical log w/o forcing it and still before any update to the store, so when the OS decides to force buffers to disk it will happen in the correct order (if your file system/OS supports ordered writes, which most modern file systems do).

In the event of a crash you may lose the last X transactions worth of data but the data that's persisted will be consistent.

NOTE it's a bit of experimental though, but feel free to try on your own risk.

Comment: Now that GraphDatabaseAPI has been deprecated/removed, how would you do this in Neo4J 2.3.1?

Comment: This solution has been deemed not safe and therefore not supported at all. Since 2.2 concurrent transactions committing are forced by piggy-backing on each other, so if there are 100 committing concurrently they might end up appending to the log (w/o forcing) and then all getting forced with a single force() call. Will this help in your scenario?